# Checking with is_array for Arrays and ArrayObjects

Tags: php

I have some **legacy code** and refactored an array to an ArrayObject. Now I have problems checking, if a variable is an array:

```
 if (is_array($entity) && $otherCondition) {
      // do something
 }
```

The function `is_array()` returns `false` on an ArrayObject. See [this report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36930).

Simplest solution would be to use something like this:

```
 function is_traversable($var) {
     return is_array($var) || $var instanceof Traversable;
 }
```

Is there some native way for PHP to do a check like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to http://blog.stuartherbert.com/php/2010/07/19/should-is_array-accept-arrayobject/, you have to make the custom method you wrote in order to do what you wish...

Comment: Thanks, the comments to this blog post are very informative. The comment #29 would be a nice answer to my question. The author shows, that different functions would be necessary and comment #39 goes into the sort problem.

Comment: PHP 7.1 now introduces `is_iterable`, a function that returns `true` for an array or an object that implements `Traversable`.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayObject does contain a method named getArrayCopy() which allow you to get an array copy of your ArrayObject. I suppose that most of array built-in functions can be applied on this copy ;)

Doc : http://php.net/manual/fr/arrayobject.getarraycopy.php

Comment: For using `getArrayCopy` I would have to know that it is an object of type ArrayObject. That would not help much if you do not have the time to rewrite a lot of old code.

Answer (score 1):

## NO

is the answer to your question. An array is an array and an object is an object.

So, if you change an array to an object you should change all the checks. I don't like your `is_traversable($var)` function because it means you only do half a job of refactoring you code. You should replace `is_array($entity)` by `$entity instanceof myEntityClass` or `is_object($entity)`.

In any case you should not see `arrays` as old fashioned. It can very well be that an array should become an object, but there's nothing wrong with arrays as such.